# include css js in view page of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

hey everyone i'm facing  a problem in codeigniter how to include css and jquery.

```
+application
  +views
    -welcome_message.php
  +assets
     +css
      -template.css
     +js
+system
+user_guide.


<link href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/assets/css/template.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

firebug show path like:-

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/application/assets/css/template.css">
```

i don't understand why it's css is not working.

i find this thing on firebug:-

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/assets/css/template.css">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /CodeIgniter_2.1.3/assets/css/template.css was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
</link>
```

Comment: and what is your question ??? the path isn't working ??

Comment: Path is correct? or what do you expect?

Comment: css in not working....

Comment: okey may be way of prviding path in not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to create an `assets` Directory **outside** the `APPLICATION` Directory **not** *inside*.

so you're directory structure would be

```
+APPLICATION
+ASSETS
+SYSTEM
```

its up to you how you divide the resources inside the ASSETS DIrectory

now you can use `base_url()/assets/your-directories/yourfiles.ext` to access whatever you wanted. Or create your own helper

i.e

```
style_url();
script_url();
image_url();
```

Answer (score 0):

Place css in root folder of site, inside assets dir and try this:

```
<link href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/template.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also, check image paths in it.

Comment: it's not working.i already tried it but sorry to say i doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Ankur Saxena: You need to move your assets folder to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/assets/css/template.css">
```

We cont use **base url** in some cases that your **site url** will include the **index.php** but your **base url** will not.And you need to give type="text/css" for this.

And also makesure that your css files should have the **permissions** to read and execute(may also)

Answer (score 0):

> So Simple

***Set Your `base_url` in `application/config/config.php` file example given below***

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your site url here';
```

***After include CSS or JS files as***

```
<!-- If Your Path is yoursitefolder/theme/css/style.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('theme/css/style.css'); ?>"> 

<!-- If Your Path is yoursitefolder/theme/js/vendor.js -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('theme/js/vendor.js'); ?>"></script>
```